# How to fire PCIe interrupt on Linux Intel Xeon

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, intel, pci-e

I am looking at a Linux-Intel-Xeon board which has a PCIe Switch (config Space shown below). On the the other side of the LinuxSwitch, via a CABLE there is a different OtherBoard running my software (non-Intel CPU, non-Linux-OS and BSP, which I understand quite well), and it has another switch and an endpoint/s (EP). From the OtherBoard I want to write to shared memory (e.g. on Linux addres 0xB000 0000), and inform **LinuxBoardCpu via MSI**.
Focusing on MSI (not general interrupts and not general enumeration).  I have two main separate questions:

Q1 How does the SW on the OtherBoard cause an MSI to the LinuxBoard, does the OtherBoard perform a write to Linux 0xFEEE_0D38 (e.g. with data=0x0 or data=0x1)? Or does the OtherBoard write 0x1 to a register on the LinuxBoard's-Switch.  I should be able to test this from the Linux side only by writing to 0xFEEE_0D38.  How do I get a ptr to that address?

Q2 Just focusing on the LinuxBoard Switch-CPU-Memory:  how do I effect the write to LinuxBoard's DRAM/DDR/memory address 0xB000_0000? It seems I need a translation of some some sort at the LinuxCPU. The LinuxSwitch will forward the write-address-data to the LinuxSwitch which forwards to the LinuxCPU, but do I need to setup the LinuxCpu to accept the access, or how does the memory-write access the  0xB000_0000?

I wrote a quick program to explore and dump the Linux PCIeBoard Switch's Config Space

04 10 BAR0              : 0x90800000 
05 14 BAR1              : 0x00000000 
08 20 MemLim, MemBase   : **0x90509050** <<<<\b
09 24 PrefetchMems LnB  : 0x90219001 
10 28 PrefetchUpBaseAdd : 0x00000000 
11 2C PrefecthLimAdd    : 0x00000000 
12 30 IoLimU16 IoBaseU16: 0x00000000 
13 34 ......Cap         : 0x00000040 
14 38 reserved          : 0x00000000 
15 3C ....InLine        : 0x001001ff 

16 40 .... MSICapPtr    : 0xc8034801 
17 44                   : 0x00000008 
18 48 MSIintCtrl Nxt ID : 0x01876805 
19 4C LowerMsgAddr      : **0xfee003d8** <<<<
20 50 UpperMsgAddr      : 0x00000000 
21 54 .... MsgData      : 0x00000000 

26 68 Cap, Nxt ID       : 0x0052a410 
27 6C DevCap            : 0x012c8003 
28 70 DevStat DevCtrl   : 0x00090830 
29 74 LnkCap            : 0x00416883 
30 78 LnkStat ..LnkCtr  : 0x10830040 
31 7C                   : 0x00000000 
32 80                   : 0x00000000

Comment: On an Intel system, any dword write to 0xFEExxxxx is an interrupt.  See section 10.11 of the Intel SDM for the format of the address and data. If interrupt remapping is enabled, see the Intel VT-d spec for the format.

Comment: The example shown, with address = fee003d8 and data = 0 definitely indicate that interrupt remapping is enabled.

Comment: The value at offset 54 is the data to be used when generating an interrupt.  Writing to this register will not trigger an interrupt. I don't know how you would cause this switch to generate the interrupt.

Comment: By the way, the MsgData register is at offset 54 in PCI config space, not in the BAR 0 region.

Comment: I can get to offset 0x5e, u32Ptr[Reg21], after "virtualizing" the BAR0, at least I assumed that that is what nmap did for me.   Based on your comment, I edited my question as it is now almost clear to me that my OtherBoard needs to do a mem-write request to the Intel Xeon.   I should be able to test that from the LinuxSide only, by writing to what? I am thinking 0xFEE003D8.  But your comment about interrupt remapping has thrown me off.

Comment: You cannot generate an interrupt using a memory write from the CPU; the write to FEExxxxx has to come from a device. (You can generate an IPI by writing to the local APIC ICR register, but that's different from an MSI from a device.)